# AngularJS | Hide Delete Icon on a Table after delete for that Item only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, scope

In my application for some technical reason, we need to verify before we delete an item from a table. That mean, when an item is marked for deletion, we need to hide the Trash Icon. I have it working, but the thing is it happens for the entire Table.

I want the Delete Icon to disappear only for that specific Item.

**HTML:**

```
<td ng-if="!hideTrashIcon">
  <a  popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" uib-popover="Delete" ng-click="deleteModal(t)">
   <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</td>
```

**CTRL:**

```
  $scope.deleteIten = function (itemName) {
    $scope.deleting = true;
    $scope.hideTrashIcon = false;

    requestAPI.deleteItem(itemName).then(function success(res) {
      $scope.deleting = false;
      $scope.hideTrashIcon = true;
      $('#delete-modal').modal('hide');
      var dItem = _.findIndex($scope.items, function(i) { return i.itemName == itemName });
      $scope.items[dItem].isMarkedForDeletion = true;
    }, function error(res) {
      $scope.deleting = false;
      $scope.hideTrashIcon = false;
      $('#delete-modal').modal('hide');      
    })
  };
```

Apparently, I am messing up when I am calling the property. I somehow need to pass the itemName to the hideTrashIcon. Can anyone help.??? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

So, to Answer my own question. Instead of using another tag, for `hideTrashIcon`, I used this:

```
ng-if="!t.isMarkedForDeletion"
```

I also, put it in a span, to avoid having the line in the table disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible you have spelling error in first line, did you mean to use “deleteIten”?

$scope.deleteIten = function (itemName) {

Comment: Thnaks for that. I just change the original code a little bit. No, in the actual code, it is fine. Thanks you though!!

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-if="!hideTrashIcon && !$scope.items[$index].isMarkedForDeletion"
```

Use the $index of the item in the ng-repeat of $scope.items as you generate the table rows.

Comment: Ok, I obviously do not get it. So here is my pagination: `<tr dir-paginate="i in items | filter : {itemName : search} | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | itemsPerPage: pageSize" >` .

What is my index in this case? I tried a lot of stuff, but I can't stop hiding everything.

Comment: On another line, I have this. `ng-if="i.isMarkedForDeletion"` . So, I tried i as the index, but still doesn't work.

Comment: What if you do:

``ng-if="!hideTrashIcon && !i.isMarkedForDeletion"``

Comment: The main problem with this is that a error is thrown, saying `isMarkedForDeletion` is not defined.

Comment: Do the items have this property? isMarkedForDeletion

Comment: Yes.. You can see my answer below. The other tag was unneccessary. `isMarkedForDeletion` was enough..Thanks for your time, man!!